# FullCalendar doesn't load without window resizing

Tags: json, resize, fullcalendar

I am trying to load fullcalendar on tab click. when I click the tab fullcalendar does not load and it load after I resize the window (or click the F12,or open the chrome inspector).

I tried some function like view rendering but it does not work..
how can I refresh view or resize fullcalendar..
or how can I load the fullcalendar on tab click without resizing..

I need help..

I use;

```
  myGenericCalendar: function (id, ajaxSourceUrl, data, eventDataTransform, eventRenderFnc, callbackFnc) {
    $(id).fullCalendar('destroy');
    $(id).fullCalendar({
        eventLimit: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        views: {
            agenda: {
                eventLimit: 6 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
            }
        },
        draggable: false,
        allDayDefault: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        ignoreTimezone: false,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            if (callbackFnc)
                callbackFnc();
            $(id).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        },
        editable: true,
        monthNames: ['Ocak', 'Şubat', 'Mart', 'Nisan', 'Mayıs', 'Haziran', 'Temmuz', 'Ağustos', 'Eylül', 'Ekim', 'Kasım', 'Aralık'],
        monthNamesShort: ["Ocak", "Şub", "Mar", "Nis", "May", "Haz", "Tem", "Ağu", "Eyl", "Ekim", "Kas", "Ara"],
        dayNames: ["Pazar", "Pazartesi", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cumartesi"],
        dayNamesShort: ["Pzr", "Pts", "Sal", "Çrş", "Prş", "Cum", "Cts"],
        titleFormat: { month: "MMMM yyyy", week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}", day: " d MMM yyyy , dddd" },
        eventDataTransform: function (eventData) {
            if (eventDataTransform)
                eventDataTransform(eventData);
            return eventData;
        },
        events: ({
            url: ajaxSourceUrl,
            data: data

        }),
        eventRender: function (calEvent, $event) {
            if (eventRenderFnc)
                eventRenderFnc(calEvent, $event)
            return $event;
            ////$event.find("div.fc-event-inner").prepend('<button class="edit btn btx-xs btn-danger btn-icon tip" data-modelid="' + calEvent.id + '" data-placement="bottom" title="Git" style="width: 20px; height: 17px;" type="button"><i class="icon-remove2"></i></button>');
            $(id).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        },
        eventClick: function (event, element) {
            if (callbackFnc)
                callbackFnc(event, element);
            $(id).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: add the code of your calendar.

Comment: I hope you can help me. added..